# Is there a way to convert an image from grayscale to RGB in "pure" Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'd like to know if there is a way to convert an image from grayscale to RGB in Python using "pure" Keras (i.e. without importing Tensorflow).

What I do now is:

```
x_rgb = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(x_grayscale)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you would consider this "cheating" (as `keras.backend` may end up calling Tensorflow behind the scene), but here's a solution:

```
from keras import backend as K

def grayscale_to_rgb(images, channel_axis=-1):
    images= K.expand_dims(images, axis=channel_axis)
    tiling = [1] * 4    # 4 dimensions: B, H, W, C
    tiling[channel_axis] *= 3
    images= K.tile(images, tiling)
    return images
```

(supposing your grayscale images have a shape `B x H x W` and not e.g. `B x H x W x 1` ; otherwise just remove the first line of the function)

Comment: Great, thanks! It's perfectly fine, I had the problem that in a Lambda layer I couldn't use any tf.* because when you loaded a saved model it didn't have tensorflow imported at that point and was raising an error. One workaround was to import tensorflow AGAIN in the method, but this is far better

Comment: Glad it helped then :)